# What is the best way to implement facebook login on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

I looked tutorial on [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) and it looks different with what I found on internet. Which one is the best way to implement facebook login? Also, where is the best place to learn facebook sdk for android, it seems the official one is not complete?

**Facebook.developer use loginButton.setRegisterCallback();**

```js
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);    
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });    
}
```

[programmerguru.com](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-implement-facebook-login-in-android-applications/) use UiLifecycleHelper which I dont find it on the official sites

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Create, automatically open (if applicable), save, and restore the 
    // Active Session in a way that is similar to Android UI lifecycles. 
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private View otherView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set View that should be visible after log-in invisible initially
        otherView = (View) findViewById(R.id.other_views);
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // To maintain FB Login session
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
     
    // Called when session changes
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
     
    // When session is changed, this method is called from callback method
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        final TextView location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        // When Session is successfully opened (User logged-in)
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            // make request to the /me API to get Graph user
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
 
                // callback after Graph API response with user
                // object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set view visibility to true
                        otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Set User name 
                        name.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                        // Set Gender
                        gender.setText("Your Gender: "
                                + user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                        location.setText("Your Current Location: "
                                + user.getLocation().getProperty("name")
                                        .toString());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
     
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");
    }
     
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the official tutorials. The reason they're different is because Facebook just released v4 of the SDK, which makes login and sharing easier. A lot of the other tutorials on the internet are still for v3 or even v2 (gasp), and are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ming Li said, stick to [the official tutorials](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android). The reason why there are many different tutorials out there are because Facebook SDK has many different version and each version may come with different way to do things with Facebook. They change it if they come up with a better idea to do things with Facebook.